# reason: -[_NSPlaceholderData initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:]: nil URL argument'

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

I am passing xml image url to the `imageview.image` then I use `datawithcontentsofurl:optionserror` like then I got this error.

The code is:

```
NSError *error=nil;
imageview.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sharedDelegate.imagObj] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error]];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
else{
    NSLog(@"loading successfully");
}
```

some images get the above error and some images loading successfully.

Comment: `sharedDelegate.imagObj` isn't a valid URL. What is its value?

Comment: in shared delegate.imageobj contains http://www.cinejosh.com/telugu/newsimg/mahesh babu-kora-1433152437-1.jpg which is in string because we can get from xml image url to array in tableview didselectrow at indexpath lo we can find this url in string so i use the nsurl urlwithstring method to send the images and some of the images are passing

Comment: That's not a valid URL. It has no scheme. You need to add `http://` or some other appropriate scheme.

Comment: http://www.cinejosh.com/telugu/newsimg/mahesh%20babu-kora-1433152437-1.jpg

Comment: the above link works it is i got and it starts http:// also

Answer (score 0):

Answer is there is spaces in between url that is the issue for that we need to add string `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding` method the i  remove the errors.

```
NSString *spaceStrObj=[sharedDelegate.imagObj stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError *error=nil;
 imageview.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:spaceStrObj] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error]];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
else{
    NSLog(@"loading successfully");
}
```